# Jasmine won't test an angular service with multiple nested promises

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to write a jasmine test case for an angular service. Since I have to do calls to a PouchDB and fetch http ressources, I use $q.

In my application I have two datasource : the PouchDB as localStorage and an XML document that is requested through http. I managed to write test for both localStorage.service and XMLparser.service without to much trouble (I had to do a 50ms timeout then a call to $rootScopre.$digest()).

However, when i try to run tests for the service that uses localStorage and XMLParser, I just can't make it pass. Karma hangs for 5 sec and the test fails at timeout. If I add some console.log() everywhere, all the code is actually executed. It's like if done() was not closing the test case. If I run the code directly in my application it works.

There's a lot going on in my code so I'll try to explain :

```
function loadCategories(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    //Json structure that tells my parser what to extract from the XML
    var structure = { ... } 

    //Check in the PouchDB to see if the structure is already cached
    localStorage.getStructure() 
    .then(function(struct){
        deferred.resolve(struct.category);
    })
    .catch(function(e){
        if(e.name != 'not_found') return deferred.reject(e);

        //If the structure is not cached, get it from the parser through an http request
        xmlparser.readFile(apiUrl, structure) 
        .then(function(doc){
            localStorage.saveStructure(doc); //Save it in the PouchDB
            deferred.resolve(doc.category); //Resolve with the categories
        })
        .catch(function(e){
            deferred.reject(e);
        });
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Here's how I'm testing it :

```
it('should list the categories', function(done){
    //The answer to this call is mocked in the beforeEach
    $httpBackend.expectGET('/lib/xmlDocuments/indicator.xml');

    var promise = Indicator.getCategories()
    .then(function(categories){
        expect(categories[0].name).toBe('Emplois par secteur d\'activité');
        expect(categories[1].name).toBe('Emplois par niveau de compétence');
        done();
        //When i put a console.log here it get executed...
    })
    .catch(function(e){
        expect(e).toBe(null);
    });

    //Here i tryed to force a $digest and then flush() the requests
    //but i still get "Async callback was not invoked within timeout"
    setTimeout(function() {
        $scope.$digest();
        setTimeout(function(){
            $httpBackend.flush();
        }, 50);
    }, 50);
});
```

Now I'm pretty sure that there's something that I'm not doing properly but I can't put my finger on it :

- Am I missusing the promisses?
- Should I mock XMLParser and localStorage?
- Is there an error in my jasmine?
- Do I over use $q?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This won't fix the issue but you shouldn't need to use `$q` in your service.  You should just be able to return `localStorage.getStructure()` since it returns a promise. If this is making an asynchronous request then you should mock it.

Comment: Well, I can't simply return localStorage.getStructure() since i need to call xmlParser.readFile() if the structure is not in the local database? Did i miss something here?

Comment: If you return a promise from inside of a promise it continues the chain.  You need to return `xmlParser.readFile` too

Comment: It would give something like that, but it does the save in both case?
`return localStorage.getStructure()
        .then(function(struct){
            console.log('Struct was found');
            return struct;
        })
        .catch(function(e){
            console.log('Struct was not found');
            if(e.name != 'not_found') return e;
            return xmlparser.readFile(apiUrl, structure)
        }).then(function(doc){
            console.log('I am saving in the database');
            localStorage.saveStructure(doc);
            return doc.category;
        });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I ended up mocking XMLParser and localStorage. I came to the conclusion that it made no sense to re-test those services again. This is a unit test, and should only test a unit.

I also modified my use of promises as suggested by Explosion Pills.

```
//Load the categories
function loadCategories(){
    var structure = { ... }

    return localStorage.getStructure()
    .then(function(struct){
        return struct.category;
    })
    .catch(function(e){
        if(e.name != 'not_found') return e;

        return xmlparser.readFile(apiUrl, structure)
        .then(function(doc){
            localStorage.saveStructure(doc);
            return doc.category;
        });
    });
}
```

I added the mocks as beforeEach

```
beforeEach(module('gisMobile', function($provide){
    xmlParserMock = {
        readFile: function(){
            var defer = $q.defer();
            defer.resolve(indicatorJsonMock);
            return defer.promise;
        }
    };

    localStorageMock = {
        isStructureCached: false,
        getStructure: function(){
            var defer = $q.defer();
            if(localStorageMock.isStructureCached)
                defer.resolve(indicatorJsonMock);
            else
                defer.reject({name: 'not_found'});
            return defer.promise;
        },
        saveStructure: function(){
            localStorageMock.isStructureCached = true;
        }
    }

    $provide.value('xmlparser', xmlParserMock);
    $provide.value('localStorage', localStorageMock);
}));
```

Finally the test now looks like

```
it('should list the categories', function(done){
    var promise = Indicator.getCategories()
    .then(function(categories){
        expect(categories[1].name).toBe('Emplois par secteur d\'activité');
        expect(categories[0].name).toBe('Emplois par niveau de compétence');
        done();
    })
    .catch(function(e){
        expect(e).toBe(null);
    });

    $rootScope.$digest();
});
```

So to close this issue, my hypothesis were right :

- I was not using the promisses properly
- I had to mock xmlParser and localStorage because they are not the target of this test.